# Grails 3 runtime error: o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory : ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor' threw an exception

Tags: spring, grails, runtime

I've been attempting to migrate my social network application nderground (nderground.net) from Grails 2 to Grails 3. The application new compiles and runs, but I am getting a runtime error. I asked this question on the Grails Slack group, but so far I've gotten nothing that helped. I've had the same result with a web search.

There have been suggestions that this was caused by Hibernate level 2 caching. I turned this off. It was no help.

There was another suggestion that this was a Spring security issue. I built with the latest version of Spring security

The Java stack trace is shown below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
2017-10-13 13:25:54.830 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2611b9a3: startup date [Fri Oct 13 13:24:55 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:556)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:388)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:375)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at nderground.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
```

Comment: Is that the only exception reported?

Comment: No, there are other exceptions, but they seem to be cascaded on this one (which is the first exception). This exception seems to result from execution of the "main()" method.

Comment: There are a number of scenarios which could cause this.  Without more information or a sample project which demonstrates the problem, it is impossible to say with certainty which scenario specifically you are dealing with.

Comment: I appreciate the posts, Jeff.  The nderground social network (nderground.net) was developed using Grails 2. I have been porting it to Grails 3. Unfortunately, I don't have a small test case that shows the problem. nderground consists of about 20K lines of Groovy/Java code. At this point, I'm going to have to start bring the application up piece by piece. This is not a pleasant prospect, but I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: As it turns out, this was caused by a somewhat obscure Grails GORM/Hibernate error, which was in turn caused by changes from Grails 2 to Grails 3. This error was at the top of the chain. Down in the chain was the Hibernate error.

Comment: "Down in the chain was the Hibernate error." - That is what I expected and why I asked the initial question above.  Glad you got it worked out.